# Why and where we can use PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

I've been working on SQL though I do not have enough knowledge on database. But still since last 1 week, I've been learning PL/SQL. I covered few basic things like how to write code, variable, different blocks etc. But my main confusion is, where should I use PL/SQL or where PL/SQL is basically used in industry ?

I'll be great full to all of you if any one give me a proper response.

Comment: This might help. https://blogs.oracle.com/plsql-and-ebr/why-use-plsql

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have some understanding of when you use `SQL`, and you are asking where `PL/SQL` comes into the equation.

`SQL` is a declarative syntax - code *what* you want and let the database figure out *how* to fulfill it. As long as the *what* is a set.

`PL/SQL` is the procedural syntax - code exactly *how* you want to fulfill *what*. And the *what* doesn't have to be a set; it can be anything like any procedural language (e.g., python, java, c#, etc.) The main difference between `PL/SQL` and those other procedural languages is that the database is the compiler and executor of the resulting compiled code. It's an intimate way to couple data access code and your database.

I hope that helps.